# CharNext(..) analog in WinRT API

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

[CharNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from WinAPI return value is a pointer to the next character in the string, but this function for desktop apps only.

Which function can replace this for Windows-RT project?

Comment: Please always be sure to read the helpful descriptions that pop up when selecting tags.  This is not a question about Windows Phone, Windows 8 or the Windows RT operating systems, it's a question about functionality in the Windows Runtime platform, commonly known as WinRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to implement one if you need it (untested code below):

```
inline bool isCombiningCharacter( wchar_t c )
{
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges
    if( c <  0x0300 ) return false;
    if( c <= 0x036F ) return true;
    if( c <  0x1DC0 ) return false;
    if( c <= 0x1DFF ) return true;
    if( c <  0x20D0 ) return false;
    if( c <= 0x20FF ) return true;
    if( c <  0xFE20 ) return false;
    if( c <= 0xFE2F ) return true;
    return false;
}

wchar_t* CharNext( wchar_t* lpsz )
{
    if( NULL == lpsz || 0 == *lpsz ) return lpsz;
    while( true )
    {
        lpsz++;
        const wchar_t nextChar = *lpsz;
        if( !isCombiningCharacter( nextChar ) || 0 == nextChar )
            return lpsz;
    }
}
```

**Update:** my sample code is for UCS-2 encoding. If you need to support UTF16 instead, you will have to add support for surrogate pairs. Lead surrogate are values 0xD800…0xDBFF, tail surrogate are 0xDC00…0xDFFF, and if a lead surrogate is encountered in the string and is followed by tail surrogate — you must skip both because they both are single Unicode character with code point >= 0x10000, only then skip combining characters that follow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using [Windows.Data.Text.UnicodeCharacters.IsGraphemeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.text.unicodecharacters.isgraphemebase.aspx) will get you most of the way to implementing [Unicode's Default Grapheme Cluster Boundary Specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table).

Something like:

```
    int NextGraphemeIndex(string s, int index)
    {
        for (++index; index != s.Length; ++index)
        {
            uint ch = s[index];
            int characterEndIndex = index;
            if (Windows.Data.Text.UnicodeCharacters.IsHighSurrogate(ch))
            {
                ++characterEndIndex;
                ch = Windows.Data.Text.UnicodeCharacters.GetCodepointFromSurrogatePair(ch, s[characterEndIndex]);
            }
            if (Windows.Data.Text.UnicodeCharacters.IsGraphemeBase(ch))
            {
                break;
            }
            index = characterEndIndex;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: @CReaTuS Added sample.